# If data missing at random, better to remove or reclassify?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, missing-data

For a multiple regression (GLM) where the explanatory variables are categorical, if we assume that `NA` values are missing at random, what are the implications of 1) dropping missing values, versus 2) classifying missing values as a separate factor and including them in the regression?

E.g. we have 100 individuals with some outcome (disease state for instance) and gender is an explanatory variable; 45 are male, 49 are female and 6 are unknown. Should we omit the unknowns and use the 94 observations in two categories (male/female), or use all 100 with three categories (male/female/unknown)?

Are there advantages / disadvantages to either approach, or is one clearly "more correct"?

Comment: If you have other predictors, multiple imputation may be the best approach.

Comment: Second @mkt.  Neither of your approaches is valid.  See the chapter on missing data in [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).